# Percentage based on column value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I am trying to find best most efficent method to calculate the percentage that each teacher is not tenured where they are teaching in my df.

For example df below:

```
District   | Teacher Name | Tenured?
  55         Bo Carns         Yes
  42         Bo Carns         No
  55         Steven Ast       No
  43         Fiona Tan        Yes
  43         Steven Ast       Yes
  43         Mike Po          No
  31         Steve Chi        No
```

Each teacher can teach in multiple districts but they can be tenured or not tenured so I wanted to calculate the % that all the teachers in my df are not tenured to find the teachers teaching that are not tenured the most ***( so for each teacher, the # of times the tenured column is no / all rows for the df )***

Expected output would be:

```
Teacher Name | pct
Bo Carns       .5
Steven Ast     .5
Fiona Tan      0
Mike Po        1
Steve Chi      1
```

where the pct is the percent they were not tenured for all records or all districts

thanks for taking time to look at my question

Comment: Can you show the expected output ?

Comment: Added expected output thanks for looking @BEN_YO

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
s = df['Tenured?'].eq('Yes').groupby(df.TeacherName).mean()
Out[57]: 
TeacherName
BoCarns      0.5
FionaTan     1.0
MikePo       0.0
SteveChi     0.0
StevenAst    0.5
Name: Tenured?, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Is there also a way to do where you can calculate percent instead of mean? Thanks

Comment: @Chris90Ch think about it , if you would like count how many 1 out  of 0 , 0, 0 ,1, 1, if you take the mean, this is equal the percentage ~